# How to obtain the SASS function that associates two specific colours?

Tags: css, sass

I have the following two colours:

```
$light-green: #99E2D0;
$dark-green: #008766;
```

I'm sure I can get the dark green from the lighter green by using a SASS function (I noticed they have the same hue). I have tried many combinations using lighten(), darken(), saturate(), etc... but have not succeeded. I ask the following question: is there a way to find out which function associates two specific colours? Do you know which function I have to use to get that colour? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use online tool to find that for you such as [Sass Colour Function Calculator](https://razorltd.github.io/sasscolourfunctioncalculator/).

In your example:

```
$light-green: #99E2D0;
$dark-green: darken(saturate($light-green, 44.27), 47.84);
```